# Replace df <- df %>% ... with a shortcut

Tags: r, magrittr

I guess most of us have already used something like this (at least if you are using the tidyverse):

```
library(tidyverse)

example <- mtcars
example <- example %>%
  select(- mpg)
```

My question:
I know there is a shortcut for this part:

```
example <- example %>% ...
```

But I can neither remember nor find it on Google.

I think it was something similar to this %<>%.

Can anyone help?

Please excuse me if this question was already asked before.

Best regards

Comment: `%<>%` is exactly what you're looking for. Look at the [magrittr docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) for a reference

Comment: Off topic, but for this particular example, a cleaner solution would be base R: `example$mpg <- NULL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `lhs %<>% rhs` from the `magrittr` package. So in your case `example %<>%
  select(- mpg)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use {dotdot} :

```
library(dotdot) 
example := .. %>%...
```

It works with everything, not just magrittr. The `..` after `:=`  are replaced by the variable.